# UI Binding not working in xamarin forms for Android device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have 6-7 properties in ViewModel. When page load first, values's of some properties not appear. but when I do Hot reload on xaml while debugging, that propertie's value does appear. Issue is happening on release version also. But in emulator, it working fine. This issue comes in Real android device only.

All that properties is made with Inotifypropertychanged. I don't know why this happening. I don't need iOS app so not tested on iOS

Comment: Try to delete the folder  `bin` and `obj` in the Android Project ,then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: Tried, but Still not working @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Try to bind that data in override method OnAppearing()